# Windows Server Task Scheduler needs files to be in System32 folder?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have made a C# console application which needs 2 config files for booting.
When I run it from cmd window it runs fine-finds the 2 config files(which are placed within the exe produced directory).

However,when using the Windows server task scheduler i get an excpetion - 
" Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\field.config' "

I tried to use a bat file for the task but same issue occurs-task scheduler tries to find the files in System32 direcory.

Placing the two config files within System32 direcory is a workaround but is there any other way?
Googled for similar issues but no information at all.
Any help is mutch appriciated.

Comment: that ir rather strange... for an answer you need to show the relevant source code where you yccess those files

Comment: Does your batch file change directory to the relevant directory, or were you just calling c:\somedir\myprog.exe ?

Comment: Thank you both for taking time to answer-used full paths as the best workaround at the moment..mayde Task Sheduler has a way to specify the Working directory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no actual code to look at, let me make an educated guess. Within your application, you are trying to open those files with paths relative to the executable (say: field.config). When you set the scheduled task, you are not properly configuring the working directory; then the application is executed with System32 as the working directory and that's why it looks for the files there.

Comment: that's exactly the case..-but you can't specifically define the working directory in the TaskCheduler.You just difine the 'Action' by giving the executable location- (C:\www.Buldoz.com\Updater\SolrUpdater.Console\bin\Debug\solrupdater.exe) and this should be the working directiry for the Task Scheduler-but it's not..it seems to be System32 since it seeks the config files there..

Comment: @Nikos: Really? I'm sure there has to be a way to specify the working directory. Anyway, you could always rewrite your application to work with full paths based on its module path.

Comment: I'll try again to find if there is a way to define the Working Directory in Task Scheduler - but yes,thats what I'am doing right now-using full paths and define them in App.config for being clear..  Thank you very much for answering..

Answer (score 19):

I know this is old but figured I'd put my finding here incase anyone stumbles on this.

On Properties>Action, it seems to be the "Start in (optional)" field on the action edit screen where you type the directory you want the working directory to be located.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I don't understand this behavior. Windows Server 2003 behaves differently and uses the 'correct' working directory by default.

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution. Saved my time.

Comment: If you are using relative path then it may still not work so always use Environment.CurrentDirectory while creating the path. Environment.CurrentDirectory path will equal to "Start in (optional)"